# gparted: cannot resize ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

I'm trying to use GParted to resize an `ext4` partition on `/dev/sda2`, and I've been watching a youtube tutorial for that. But my `/dev/sda2` cannot be resized. I've tried to change the number but it kept returning to the previous value. I've tried to use cursor but still cannot. when I saw on youtube it could reduce the partition size just shifting dev/sda2.
I cannot shift the `/dev/sda2` by the cursor and resize that.

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome! Note the "keys" icons. To modify partitions they need to be unmounted, and if you are actually using them, that's not possible, unless you do it from a live USB.

Comment: Before changing partitions, always do a proper backup of your data, since it's a risky bussiness.

Comment: REMEMBER TO UNMOUNT. That is exactly what @schrodingerscatcuriosity said above but I only managed to read their first sentence because - squirrel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

**Note**: this assumes an ext4 partition for /dev/sda2, and that you wish to reduce the partition size.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda2 to the left as far as desired
- click the Apply icon